# I cannot figure out why my environment does not include the command python as detailed below:

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, environment

This is ubuntu 22.04 in WSL.
I do not think WSL is important here.
I have built an environment with python 3.8.
The ubuntu distribution is at python 3.10
I use virtualenvwrapper to invoke the environment, 38env.
So after activating 38env (workon 38env is the command)
`PATH` is modified
from

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/username/.local/bin
```

to

```
/home/username/.venvs/38env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/username/.local/bin
```

```
(38env) username@DEVICE:~/.venvs/38env/bin$ ls -l |grep python
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username   248 Jan 14 06:40 ipython
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username   248 Jan 14 06:40 ipython3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username username     9 Jan 13 12:16 python -> python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username username     9 Jan 13 12:16 python3 -> python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username username    40 Jan 13 12:16 python3.8 -> /home/username/.localpython/bin/python3.8
```

So now for the python command; first without 38env:

```
username@DEVICE:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
username@DEVICE:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
username@DEVICE:~$ python -V
Python 3.10.12
username@DEVICE:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.12
```

(all quite sensible)

```
Now activate 38env:
username@DEVICE:~$ workon 38env
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$ which python
/home/username/.venvs/38env/bin/python
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$ which python3
/home/username/.venvs/38env/bin/python3
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$ python -V
Python 3.10.12      !! WHY?
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.3
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$ /home/username/.venvs/38env/bin/python -V
Python 3.8.3
(38env) username@DEVICE:~$
```

I simply do not understand why python still points to `/usr/bin/python`.

I expected `python` and `/home/username/.venvs/38env/bin/python`
to be identical. This is a feature that can cause a lot of trouble if
one innocently types `python` rather than `python3` within 38env.

Comment: Did you create the environment using `virtualenvwrapper`, or are you just using it to activate a pre-existing environment? Any particular reason that you're using it over the built-in `venv` module or other tools?

Comment: I used $HOME/.localpython/bin/python3.8 -m venv ~/.venvs/38env to create and then used pip within $HOME/.localpython/bin to install virtualenvwrapper & virtualenv. thn my .bashrc has export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.venvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/home/username/.localpython/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /home/username/.localpython/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: I haven't used `virtualenvwrapper` since the Python 2 days. Does it do something that you aren't getting with the built-in `venv` module? Have you tried simply `source`ing `~/.venvs/38env/bin/activate`? My gut says `virtualenvwrapper` might be the source of the problem.

Comment: (Side note, it's usually better to create a new environment for each _project_, not just each Python version.)

Comment: I think you're running into something like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Answer (score 0):

I tried Fedora and got the same result so I decided to look for something I do wrong - and found it in my .bashrc:  alias python=`which python3`.
This is terrible and I will never do it again. I have carried this in my environment from the days of python2. It really can mess up the environment and might never be seen unless you were building environments with a different version of python or you very carefully inspected your python -m site results.
So it was not WSL or Ubuntu or Fedora; it was me!